# Members only function, but allow account activation [solved]

Tags: functions, multisite, members

I have small multisite and one of site is restricted. When you go site you will see login page first because this function:

```php
function members_only() {
    global $pagenow;
    // Check to see if user in not logged in and not on the login page
    if( !is_user_logged_in() && $pagenow != 'wp-login.php' )
       auth_redirect();
    add_action( 'wp', 'members_only' );
```

Problem is when I add a new user in site and user gets activation link
`domain.com/wp-activate.php?key=abcde132456`

... and they click it, they go straight to the login because of that function and the user account won't activate because `wp-activate.php` page wont show.

I would be thankful for the tricks. Maybe some if function only `wp-activate.php` site?

Comment: Could you check against `$pagenow` like you do for wp-login.php?

Comment: Of course! Thank you I got it working! :)